# discord.py - deleting non-attachments and giving reaction to attachments

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted do a event for memes channel and something is wrong. Please help me!
Problem:

```
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx, message):
    if ctx.channel.id == 767024938397204480:
        if not ctx.message.attachments:
            channel = bot.get_channel(781226296079286282)
            ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        else:
            emoji = bot.get_emoji(767071605364883476)
            emoji2 = bot.get_emoji(767071623048069130)
            await message.add_reaction(emoji)
            await message.add_reaction(emoji2)
```

Comment: The error was raised when the function `on_message` was called. Based on the error, you are calling `on_message` without passing any argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_message` only takes one argument, `message`, only commands take the `context`, also you should add `bot.process_commands` at the end of the event so commands will work.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # ...

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Please read the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.on_message)